# Save scanned MCQ question as separate image using python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, crop

I've a scanned MCQ image. Please find image attached.
It has question and choices.
My goal is to crop each question and save separate image.
[image: MCQ scanned]

Here is my code in python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import os
import re

# Path to the input image
image_path = r'd:\Users\Desktop\Sample\input.jpg'

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Use pytesseract to perform OCR on the image
ocr_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray_image, config='--psm 6')

# Find all occurrences of question numbers
matches = list(re.finditer(r'\d+\)', ocr_result))

# Define the output directory
output_dir = r'd:\Users\Desktop\Sample'

# Iterate over the matches to split each question as a separate image
for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    question_number = match.group()  # Get the question number
    start_x = 0  # Start X coordinate
    start_y = match.start()  # Start Y coordinate
    if i < len(matches) - 1:
        end_y = matches[i + 1].start() - 4  # End Y coordinate (4 pixels above the next question)
    else:
        end_y = gray_image.shape[0]  # End Y coordinate (end of the image)
    end_x = gray_image.shape[1]  # End X coordinate (end of the image)
    
    # Crop the image
    question_image = gray_image[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x]

    # Save the cropped image
    output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f'question_{i + 1}.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(output_path, question_image)
    print(f"Question {i + 1} saved at: {output_path}")

# Display the number of questions found
print(f"Number of questions found: {len(matches)}")
```

But, for some reason(s), it doesn't work (i.e) the images are not cropped properly. Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Have you reviewed the values for x,y that you get from your matches to see that they are correct?